# Calling a defined variable inside a function which is in for loop, R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have a problem inside for loop in R while calling a variable inside compute function. I have used neuralnet package and i have computed six different ann (artificial neural network) variable. These are stored in Values section of environment window.

```
for (i in 1:6) {

predictions = compute(paste("neuralmodel_t",i, sep=""),new_pred[,1:4])

}
```

The resulting error for this loop is;

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Normally, i can run these functions seperately. For instance, function that is at the below works;

```
compute(neuralmodel_t1,new_pred[,1:4])
```

So, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command

```
paste("neuralmodel_t",i, sep="")
```

does just create a string, it does not access the variable with the correspoding name. You have to use `get`.

```
for (i in 1:6) {
  predictions = compute(get(paste("neuralmodel_t", i, sep = "")), new_pred[, 1:4])
}
```